# Unable to exceute mean of list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of the following type

```
a=[[0.        , 0.03846154, 0.34615385, 0.34615385, 0.42307692,
       0.42307692, 0.53846154, 0.53846154, 0.61538462, 0.61538462,
       0.65384615, 0.65384615, 0.73076923, 0.73076923, 0.76923077,
       0.76923077, 0.80769231, 0.80769231, 0.88461538, 0.88461538,
       0.92307692, 0.92307692, 0.96153846, 0.96153846, 1.        ,
       1.        ], [0.        , 0.03846154, 0.61538462, 0.61538462, 0.69230769,
       0.69230769, 0.73076923, 0.73076923, 0.76923077, 0.76923077,
       0.80769231, 0.80769231, 0.84615385, 0.84615385, 0.88461538,
       0.88461538, 0.92307692, 0.92307692, 0.96153846, 0.96153846,
       1.        , 1.        ], [0.        , 0.03846154, 0.34615385, 0.34615385, 0.42307692,
       0.42307692, 0.61538462, 0.61538462, 0.69230769, 0.69230769,
       0.73076923, 0.73076923, 0.76923077, 0.76923077, 0.80769231,
       0.80769231, 0.84615385, 0.84615385, 0.88461538, 0.88461538,
       0.92307692, 0.92307692, 0.96153846, 0.96153846, 1.        ,
       1.        ], [0.        , 0.03846154, 0.42307692, 0.42307692, 0.57692308,
       0.57692308, 0.76923077, 0.76923077, 0.84615385, 0.84615385,
       0.88461538, 0.88461538, 0.92307692, 0.92307692, 0.96153846,
       0.96153846, 1.        , 1.        ]]
```

I am trying to compute the mean of this list of list. I am using the following code.

```
mean_a=[float(sum(col))/len(col) for col in zip(*a)]
```

But I am getting the following output.

```
 0.03846154,
 0.43269231,
 0.43269231,
 0.5288461525,
 0.5288461525,
 0.66346154,
 0.66346154,
 0.7307692325,
 0.7307692325,
 0.7692307675,
 0.7692307675,
 0.8173076925,
 0.8173076925,
 0.8557692299999999,
 0.8557692299999999,
 0.89423077,
 0.89423077]
```

As you can see the output is wrong as the all the last elements of each list is 1 and so the mean should be 1. But I am getting a different mean for the last element.

Comment: What should be the dimension, the shape, and the type of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the number of elements in each lists are different. (26 , 22 , 26 , 18)

**Zip()** function uniformly maps all elements of lists of same sizes. *(And that's why the 1's are missing and would round off to 18 elements)*

Try maintaining the same number of elements in each List and try to find the mean again.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether this statement is correct or not " all the last elements of each list is 1 and so the mean should be 1. But I am getting a different mean for the last element."

Mean is just sum of all elements divided by number of observation.

Comment: They are of different lengths as pointed above in the accepted answer. Sorry I missed that part